# How to get first child of JObject without using foreach loop

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to get the first child of `JObject`.
This is how I temporarily solved it with foreach loop breaking after first iteration.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> item in (JObject)json["stats"])
{
    // doing something with item
    break;
}
```

I wonder if there is shorter solution, like `json["stats"][0]` (however it doesn't work this way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably a few ways, but here's one:

```
JToken prop = obj["stats"].First;
```

If you know it's a `JProperty`:

```
JProperty prop = obj["stats"].First.ToObject<JProperty>();
```

Comment: I think it's best answer, because it uses native methods and does not require LINQ extensions. However, to get actual item it needs casting. `JObject item = (obj["stats"].First as JProperty).Value as JObject` You can update your answer if someone else needs it.

Comment: @stil: A little cleaner would be `obj["stats"].First.ToObject<JProperty>().Value` if you *know* that it's a `JProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `JObject` implements `IDicionary<string, JToken>` you can use Linq extension methods.

```
 IDictionary<string, JToken> json = new JObject();
 var item = json.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
(json["stats"] as JObject).Select(x =>
      {
            // do something with the item;

            return x;
      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to the "stats" by selecting token and access the first object in it.

```
var first = jo.SelectToken("stats").First;
```